# validation error message:The field PositionId must be a number

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have three radio buttons and a dropdownlist for positions. Based on selection of radio buttons, items in the dropdownlist gets populated dynamically using JSON. 
While validation, it is showing validation error message : "The field PositionId must be a number."
where as it should be "Please select Position". Code is given below. Please guide me. Thank you.

View:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align: right;">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CompanyType, "", new { id = "India", @checked = true, onclick = "ShowHideControls('India')", style = "margin-bottom:5px"})</div>
                <div class="span3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyType, "India")</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align: right;">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CompanyType, "", new { id = "USA", onclick = "ShowHideControls('USA')", style = "margin-bottom:5px"})</div>
                <div class="span3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyType, "USA")</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align: right;">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CompanyType, "", new { id = "UK", onclick = "ShowHideControls('UK')", style = "margin-bottom:5px" })</div>
                <div class="span3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyType, "UK")</div>
            </div>
</div>
<div id="position" class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PositionId, "Position")</div>
                <div class="span3">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PositionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PositionList, "--Please select Position--", new { id = "PositionList" })</div>
                <div class="span4"><font color="red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PositionId)</font></div> 
            </div>

function getPositions(code) 
{
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Registration/GetPositions";
    var ddltarget = '#PositionList';
    $.getJSON(url, { Code: code }, function (data) {
    $(ddltarget).empty();
    $(ddltarget).append("<option>--Please select Position--</option>");
    $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
    $(ddltarget).append("<option value=" + optionData.Value + ">" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
   });
  });
}

Controller:
public JsonResult GetPositions(string code)
{
 DataTable dt = registrationBLO.GetParameters(code);
 List<SelectListItem> positions = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
             positions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["PARAM_VALUE"].ToString(), Value = dr["PARAM_ID"].ToString() });
        }
        return Json(positions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Model:
public class Registration
{
    public int CompanyType { get; set; }
 
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Position")]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are the `value` attributes of all the options (including the dynamically loaded ones) numeric?

Comment: yes. option values are numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the html generated by the helper, you will see something like

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PositionID must be a number." data-val-required="Please select Position" id="PositionID" name="PositionID" class="input-validation-error">....</select>
```

Note that the first `data-val-` attribute is `data-val-number="The field PositionID must be a number."` This is a result of the `HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method that is called internally by `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to render the html.

Unobtrusive validation works by parsing the element and looping each `data-val-` attribute so the first 'rule' that is added is to validate its a number. If you attempt to submit the form and the "Please select Position" option has been selected the validator responds with the first error which is `"The field PositionID must be a number."` (it does not continue to check for more errors and concatenate them all)

Note that your property is `int` so the `[Required]` is not actually necessary (an `int` must always have a value so the `data-val-required` is added anyway).

Unless you were to change the property to a `string`, then what you are seeing is the default behaviour.

Note also: when you add a 'label' option using javascript, you should give it a 'null' value otherwise it will post back the text of the 'label'

```
$(ddltarget).append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Please select Position--'));
```

which will generate

```
<option value>--Please select Position--</option>
```

without `.val('')`, it would generate

```
<option>--Please select Position--</option>
```

which means that `"--Please select Position--"` would be posted back